# heroku using git branch is confusing!

Tags: git, version-control, merge, github, heroku

Ok, so I have a big github project that i'm not supposed to merge my little Stacia branch into. However, it seems like Heroku only takes pushing MASTER seriously. It looks like I pushed my branch, but for example if I only have my branch, it even acts like there's no code on the server. I can't even get my gems installed since the .gems file is on my branch.

Basically I don't even want Heroku to know there's a master. I just want to use my test Stacia branch. But it keeps ignoring my local branch. Is there a way to do this? And again, I don't want to overwrite anything on the main Github repository (eeek!) but it would be ok probably if I had both master and my branch on heroku and merged them there.

I am a total git novice (on windows no less) so please bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is make sure you have rebase your local branch on top of its master (Let's suppose it is in its repo 'mainGitHubRepo')

```
git fetch mainGitHubRepo master
git checkout -b mainGitHubMaster mainGitHubRepo/master
```

Then go back to your branch and replay it on top of mainGitHubMaster :

```
git checkout Stacia
git rebase mainGitHubMaster
```

As [georgebrock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5168/georgebrock) mentions in the comment, you don't have to create the intermediate local branch `mainGitHubMaster`: you can directly rebase on top of the fetch branch.

```
git checkout Stacia
git rebase maingithubrepo/master
```

After that, you can push your [branch to your GitHub fork](http://github.com/guides/push-a-branch-to-github), and then make a [pull request](http://github.com/guides/pull-requests).

> To push a local branch to an established remote, you simply need to use:
>   `git push REMOTENAME BRANCHNAME`.
>   If you don’t want to use the same name on the remote branch you can use:
>   `git push REMOTENAME LOCALBRANCHNAME:REMOTEBRANCHNAME`.

(which is what [David Dollar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/117630/david-dollar) mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823397/heroku-using-git-branch-is-confusing/2111882#2111882): `git push heroku yourbranch:master`)

Note: if you have your own fork on GitHub, you could work directly on 'master' for this fork, meaning your pull request would come from a 'master' branch, enhancing your chances to be considered.
But the aforementioned process remains valid: your pull request must result in trivial merges for the one who will integrate your changes, hence the rebase step to be made locally.

Comment: You can skip a step in this process by rebasing onto the remote tracking branch without creating a local branch: `git fetch maingithubrepo; git checkout stacia; rebase maingithubrepo/master`

Comment: @georgebrock good point, I have included it in the answer for more visibility

Answer (score 58):

If you want to push a different branch to Heroku you can do something like

```
git push heroku yourbranch:master
```